# How do I drop to Emacs mode for one command in Evil mode?

Tags: evil

In vim, I can do `C-O` in insert mode and drop to normal mode for one command.
Is there a way I can do this in evil, except dropping to Emacs mode for one command?
e.g. `C-Q C-x C-f` where `C-Q` is in vim mode and `C-x C-f` is in emacs mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal and visual state, `\` is bound to `evil-execute-in-emacs-state`, which does exactly what you're looking for. For instance, `\ C-t` in normal state will run `transpose-chars` and remain in normal state afterwards.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for your help.